# Need to export information from a JSON file that I thought was a key pair but not returning as such

Tags: python, json, count, key, extract

I am trying to export Instance Types along with a count of each instance type from a JSON file using Python.  I only need the InstanceType along with the type and a count of each of the instance types produced.

The following is a snippet of the JSON file:

```
 "InstanceTypes": [
    {
        "InstanceType": "c7gn.xlarge",
        "CurrentGeneration": true,
        "FreeTierEligible": false,
        "SupportedUsageClasses": [
            "on-demand",
            "spot"
        ],
        "SupportedRootDeviceTypes": [
            "ebs"
        ],
        "SupportedVirtualizationTypes": [
            "hvm"
        ],
        "BareMetal": false,
        "Hypervisor": "nitro",
        "ProcessorInfo": {
            "SupportedArchitectures": [
                "arm64"
            ],
            "SustainedClockSpeedInGhz": 2.6
        },
        "VCpuInfo": {
            "DefaultVCpus": 4,
            "DefaultCores": 4,
            "DefaultThreadsPerCore": 1,
            "ValidCores": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4
            ],
            "ValidThreadsPerCore": [
                1
            ]
        },
        "MemoryInfo": {
            "SizeInMiB": 8192
        },
        "InstanceStorageSupported": false,
        "EbsInfo": {
            "EbsOptimizedSupport": "default",
            "EncryptionSupport": "supported",
            "EbsOptimizedInfo": {
                "BaselineBandwidthInMbps": 2083,
                "BaselineThroughputInMBps": 260.375,
                "BaselineIops": 8333,
                "MaximumBandwidthInMbps": 10000,
                "MaximumThroughputInMBps": 1250.0,
                "MaximumIops": 40000
            },
            "NvmeSupport": "required"
        },
        "NetworkInfo": {
            "NetworkPerformance": "Up to 40 Gigabit",
            "MaximumNetworkInterfaces": 4,
            "MaximumNetworkCards": 1,
            "DefaultNetworkCardIndex": 0,
            "NetworkCards": [
                {
                    "NetworkCardIndex": 0,
                    "NetworkPerformance": "Up to 40 Gigabit",
                    "MaximumNetworkInterfaces": 4,
                    "BaselineBandwidthInGbps": 12.5,
                    "PeakBandwidthInGbps": 40.0
                }
            ],
            "Ipv4AddressesPerInterface": 15,
            "Ipv6AddressesPerInterface": 15,
            "Ipv6Supported": true,
            "EnaSupport": "required",
            "EfaSupported": false,
            "EncryptionInTransitSupported": true,
            "EnaSrdSupported": false
        },
        "PlacementGroupInfo": {
            "SupportedStrategies": [
                "cluster",
                "partition",
                "spread"
            ]
        },
        "HibernationSupported": false,
        "BurstablePerformanceSupported": false,
        "DedicatedHostsSupported": true,
        "AutoRecoverySupported": true,
        "SupportedBootModes": [
            "uefi"
        ],
        "NitroEnclavesSupport": "unsupported",
        "NitroTpmSupport": "unsupported"
    },
```

The following is sample code that I attempted to use. When i execute it it tells me instance type cannot be found.  I also confirmed this with another python script and was told it did not exist with that script either.  I believe I need to build another library or list first but unsure how to do this and parse it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am just starting my journey.

My code is below:

```
import json

def extract_string_from_json(json_file_path, key):
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        # Navigate through the JSON structure to access the specific string
        # For example, if the string is nested within dictionaries and lists:
        string_value = data.get(key, "Key not found")
        return string_value

# Example usage:

json_file_path = r'C:\Users\Path\Documents\ptah\Python\path\data.json'  # Replace 'data.json'  
with your JSON file path
key_to_extract = 'InstanceType'  # Replace 'specific_key' with the key containing the string

string_value = extract_string_from_json(json_file_path, key_to_extract)
if string_value != "Key not found":
    print("String value:", string_value)
else:
    print(f"Key '{key_to_extract}' not found in JSON file.")
```

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Your sample is not valid/complete json.

Comment: Typo: `InstanceType` != `InstanceTypes`

Comment: `InstanceType` is in a nested dictionary in a list. You need `data['InstanceTypes'][0]['InstanceType']`

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for the response.  I am still not sure I know quite how to use this. Do you have an example you could provide?  Thanks!